# Trigger will not fire, picklist value always returns null

Tags: apex, trigger, picklist, null

In an apex "before update" trigger, I have a conditional statement based on a picklist value. However, this conditional statement never fires because the picklist value always returns null.

```
trigger NewProposalPQ on Proposal__c (before update) {
    List<ProdQueue__c> peecues = new List<ProdQueue__c>();
    for (Proposal__c p: trigger.new){
        system.debug(p.name);
        system.debug(p.Request_BOV_from_Production__c);
        system.debug(p.BOV_Created__c);
        if (p.Request_BOV_from_Production__c == 'YES' && p.BOV_Created__c == False){
            ProdQueue__c pq = new ProdQueue__c(name = p.name, Proposal__c = p.Id,Production_Type__c='BOV');
            if(p.Client__c != null){
                pq.Client__c = p.Client__c;  
            }
            if(p.Property__c != null){
                pq.property__c = p.property__c;
            }
            peecues.add(pq);
            insert peecues;
            p.production__c = pq.id;
            p.BOV_Created__c = True;
        }
    }
}
```

In my debug log, the value of `p.Request_BOV_from_Production__c` is always null.

Comment: Have you double checked the Field Level Security settings of your `Request_BOV_from_Production__c` field to make sure that you (or the user you're testing as) can read the field? If that's not the issue, are your org's profiles set to be able to read the field?

Comment: can you explain more briefly because Request_BOV_from_Production__c always null means..@MRG

Comment: How is the field being set? By a workflow? By a user? A process?

Comment: it's set by the user

Comment: pretty much just your everyday picklist field

Comment: Try creating a test class so you know you'll have valid data. Insert a record and set a value for the picklist. Then do an update which should fire your trigger. That should help you troubleshoot your issue. Be sure to use a `RunAs()` user and use `Test.StartTest()`, etc. If it happens there, that will help you find the source of the issue when the record is saved in the insert.

Comment: As an aside to the question, you should move the `insert peecues;` line to outside of the for loop, as it will cause an excess amount of DML statements to be executed

Comment: Can I do that? I thought that it would not assign the id of pq to p.production__c unless pq had been inserted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An answer to your issue about not being able to do this trigger's work without performing DML in a loop... you've just got to get a little fancier in your implementation.

```
trigger NewProposalPQ on Proposal__c (before update) {
    List<ProdQueue__c> prodQueuesToInsert = new List<ProdQueue__c>();

    for (Proposal__c p: trigger.new){
        system.debug(p.name);
        system.debug(p.Request_BOV_from_Production__c);
        system.debug(p.BOV_Created__c);
        if (p.Request_BOV_from_Production__c == 'YES' && p.BOV_Created__c == false) {

            ProdQueue__c pq = new ProdQueue__c(Name = p.Name
                                            , Proposal__c = p.Id
                                            , Production_Type__c = 'BOV');

            if (p.Client__c != null) {
                pq.Client__c = p.Client__c;  
            }
            if (p.Property__c != null) {
                pq.property__c = p.property__c;
            }

            prodQueuesToInsert.add(pq);

        }
    }

    // is there DML work to do?
    if (!prodQueuesToInsert.isEmpty()) {
        insert prodQueuesToInsert;

        // loop over the ProdQueue records and get their new ids
        // and associate them with the Proposal__c record
        for (ProdQueue__c pQueue : prodQueuesToInsert) {

            // get the original Proposal__c record from the newMap
            // using the relationship set earlier
            Proposal__c p = trigger.newMap.get(pQueue.Proposal__c);

            // set this pQueue Id on the related Proposal__c
            p.Production__c = pQueue.Id;
            p.BOV_Created__c = true;
            // because this is a before update, the Proposal__c here
            // will have a reference to this ProdQueue__c record when finished
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `isEmpty` check doesn't really add anything.

Comment: [You are correct](/a/19401/660) from a DML limits perspective. I don't presume to know what other logic might be performed if the list is not empty, so I added it to contain all of the 'post processing' logic.

Comment: Ah gotcha. The post processing you have in there wouldn't be affected either, but it makes sense that there might be other logic.

Answer (score 2):

Just for your own education (@MarkPond has the correct answer, be sure to give him credit) here's an alternate, fewer lines solution.  Note the elimination of the if tests to set `productQueue__c.client__c` and `property__c`. If the `Proposal__c` has null values then no reason not to copy null into the `ProdQueue__c` fields.

```
trigger NewProposalPQ on Proposal__c (before update) {
  List<ProdQueue__c> pqInsList = new List<ProdQueue__c>();

  for (Proposal__c p: trigger.new){
    if (p.Request_BOV_from_Production__c == 'YES' && !p.BOV_Created__c) 
        pqInsList.add(new ProdQueue__c(
                                     Name = p.Name
                                   , Proposal__c = p.Id
                                   , Production_Type__c = 'BOV'
                                   , Client__c = p.client__c
                                   , Property__c = p.property__c
                              );

  }

  insert pqInsList; // no DML burned if list is empty

    // link the triggered Proposals to the created ProdQueues. 
    // Before update implicitly adds these values to the object being saved.
  for (ProdQueue__c pq : pqInsList) {
    trigger.newMap.get(pq.Proposal__c).Production__c = pq.id; 
    trigger.newMap.get(pq.Proposal__c).BOV_created__c = true;
  }

}
```

Normally, one does related object DML in an after trigger but because of the two-way linking, that code would be more complex as you have to avoid recursion when updating the Proposal__c records so I can see why you went this route.